# Django get_or_create not creating new record in the model

Tags: python, django

I'm having issue with the get_or_create statement. It gets the record if there is one but isnt creating a record. I have defaults in all of my model fields.

My view.py

```
    from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponseRedirect, Http404, get_object_or_404
from django.contrib.auth import logout, login, authenticate
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib import messages
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

# Create your views here.
from .models import UserProfile



@login_required
def profile_view(request):
    user = request.user
    account = request.user
    profile = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(UserProfile, user=user)
    context = {'profile': profile, 'account': account, }
    template = 'profiles/profile.html'  
    return render(request, template, context)
```

The traceback im getting is:

```
ypeError at /profiles/
get_or_create() takes exactly 1 argument (3 given)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/profiles/
Django Version: 1.6.5
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
get_or_create() takes exactly 1 argument (3 given)
```

The models.py im working on is:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
city = models.CharField(max_length=120, default="Add your city")
country = models.CharField(max_length=120, default="Add your country") #(max_length=2, choices=[(x[0], x[3]) for x in country.COUNTRIES])
zipcode = models.CharField(max_length=8, default="Add your zip/postcode")
birthyear = models.IntegerField(max_length=4, default="Add your birthyear")
timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)

def __unicode__(self):
    return str(self.user.username)

class Meta:
    ordering = ['-updated', '-timestamp']
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to pass the model class to the method.

```
profile = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(UserProfile, user=user)
```

should be

```
profile, created = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
```

Comment: Also, get_or_create returns a tuple: (instance, created) where created is True if the record didn't already exist in the database.

Comment: 'ValueError at /profiles/
Cannot assign "5": "UserProfile.user" must be a "User" instance.
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/profiles/
Django Version: 1.6.5
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value: 
Cannot assign "5": "UserProfile.user" must be a "User" instance.'

Comment: Hi Rod, I have altered this and am now getting the traceback as above/

Comment: @RodXavier i have edited the answer and still getting the traceback error 'Exception Value: 
Cannot assign "5": "UserProfile.user" must be a "User" instance.'

Comment: this part `user = request.user.id` should be `user=request.user`

Comment: The issue you're seeing, UK2AU, is occurring because the value in 'user' is the user's *id*. Rod Xavier's answer will work, but if you *need* the id, you can alternatively do this: `user_id=user`.

Comment: i still had 'user = request.user.id' which was causing the error chnaged to 'user = request.user' and its working now. Thank you @RodXavier & bmhkim